# Assert error in java

Tags: java, assert

probably newbie error here. I copied the `assert` code directly from the book, but the `AssertionError` isn't being thrown. If I enter a value lower than 0or higher than 10 execution continues normally.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssertExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("enter a number between 0 and 10: ");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();

        assert (number >= 0 && number <= 10) : "bad number: " + number;

        System.out.println("You entered " + number);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

---

```
enter a number between 0 and 10: -3
You entered -3
```

Comment: possible duplicate [how to enable java keyword assert in Eclipse in program wise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415160/how-to-enable-java-keyword-assert-in-eclipse-in-program-wise)

Comment: Don't use `assert` to validate user input since they're not guaranteed to run: http://stackoverflow.com/a/298973/20394

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AssertionError isn't being thrown.

Add `-ea` (enabling assertions) to the Java command arguments when running your application.

Answer (score 1):

You must run the program with assertions enabled.

```
java -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
```